# I need a Hotkey, for example "c" to enable the script

Tags: autohotkey

This is the current working script, but I need a hotkey to activate it and not have it activated by clicking on run.

```
#SingleInstance, Force

SetTimer, PressTheKey, 0

return

PressTheKey:

Send, {y}

Send, {LButton}

return

ExitApp
x::ExitApp
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#SingleInstance, Force

c::Send, y{LButton}

x::ExitApp
```